# Remove duplicates from SQL query result in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have written SQL query and got following results, but i want to remove duplicates year from my result on the basis of min(sales) for every products.

```
                SELECT petroleum_product AS Product,
                CAST(year / 5 * 5 AS CHAR) || '-' || 
                    CAST(year / 5 * 5 + 4 AS CHAR) AS Year,                       
                MIN(sale) AS MIN,      
                MAX(sale) AS Max,
                AVG(sale) AS AVG
                FROM REPORT
                GROUP BY Product, Year
                ORDER BY 2;
```

I got following results from this query:

```
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2000-2004', 63131, 63131, 63131.0)  
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2000-2004', 47453, 47453, 47453.0)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2000-2004', 52839, 52839, 52839.0)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2000-2004', 64041, 64041, 64041.0)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2000-2004', 66825, 66825, 66825.0)
('Diesel', '2000-2004', 326060, 326060, 326060.0)
('Diesel', '2000-2004', 286233, 286233, 286233.0)
('Diesel', '2000-2004', 299973, 299973, 299973.0)
('Diesel', '2000-2004', 299730, 299730, 299730.0)
('Diesel', '2000-2004', 315368, 315368, 315368.0)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2010-2014', 101314, 101314, 101314.0)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2010-2014', 109808, 109808, 109808.0)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2010-2014', 115786, 115786, 115786.0)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2010-2014', 123527, 123527, 123527.0)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2010-2014', 139404, 139404, 139404.0)
('Diesel', '2010-2014', 655128, 655128, 655128.0)
('Diesel', '2010-2014', 648513, 648513, 648513.0)
('Diesel', '2010-2014', 716747, 716747, 716747.0)
('Diesel', '2010-2014', 811100, 811100, 811100.0)
('Diesel', '2010-2014', 901393, 901393, 901393.0)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2005-2009', 64335, 64335, 64335.0)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2005-2009', 63778, 63778, 63778.0)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2005-2009', 68938, 68938, 68938.0)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2005-2009', 68935, 68935, 68935.0)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2005-2009', 82631, 82631, 82631.0)
('Diesel', '2005-2009', 294329, 294329, 294329.0)
('Diesel', '2005-2009', 306687, 306687, 306687.0)
('Diesel', '2005-2009', 302706, 302706, 302706.0)
('Diesel', '2005-2009', 446468, 446468, 446468.0)
('Diesel', '2005-2009', 612505, 612505, 612505.0)
```

After my query every product of every year range there are 5 results. But i want the final result to have min(sale) which is min among those 5, max(sale) maximium among those 5 and avg(sale) which is avg of those 5. Same goes for products of other year ranges aswell.

The result after query should be something like this:

```
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2000-2004', 47453, 66825, 58857.8)
('Diesel', '2000-2004', 286233, 66825, 305472.8)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2005-2009', 63778, 82631, 69723.4)
('Diesel', '2005-2009', 294329, 612505, 392539)
('Aviation Turbine Fuel', '2010-2014', 101314, 139404, 117967.8)
('Diesel', '2010-2014', 648513, 901393, 746576.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (
    select 
        petroleum_product as product,
        cast(year / 5 * 5 as char) || '-' || cast(year / 5 * 5 + 4 as char) as year,                       
        min(sale) as min_sale,
        max(sale) as max_sale,
        avg(sale) as avg_sale,
        row_number() over(partition by product order by min(sale)) rn
    from report
    group by product, year
) t
where rn = 1
order by 2;
```

Starting from your existing query, this gives the row with the least `min(sale)` for each `product`.

Comment: This code is only giving one product of one year range though that product has other year ranges aswell. Like Diesel has '2000-2004', '2005-2009', '2010-2014' and so on. Same goes for other products as well.  What I want is Diesel, petrol,....... should have single value from every year ranges and that value should be on the basis of min value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT Product, 
       Year,
       MIN(min_sale) AS MIN,
       MAX(max_sale) AS MAX,
       AVG(avg_sale) AS AVG
FROM (
  SELECT petroleum_product AS Product,
         (year / 5 * 5) || '-' || (year / 5 * 5 + 4) AS Year,       
         MIN(sale) AS min_sale,      
         MAX(sale) AS max_sale,
         AVG(sale) AS avg_sale
  FROM REPORT
  GROUP BY Product, Year
)
GROUP BY Product, Year
```

There is no need to cast integer values to `CHAR` before you concatenate them.